# Invalid Columns using EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity, dbcontext

Can someone please help me with this problem? I am new to EF and i don't know what happen to this code:

Please find below query in the **Controller**:

```
foreach (var i in tt)
{
    db.tbl_transaction.Add(i);
    db.tbl_transactionlist.Add(tm.tlist);

    var tools = (from j in db.tbl_tools_and_equips where j.itemno == i.controlno select j).First();
    //tools.location = i.destinationid;
    //tools.linemodel = i.line_model;
    //tools.usage = i.process_assign;
    tools.status = i.status;
    tools.date_maintain = i.date_maintain;
    tools.date_next_maintain = i.date_next_maintain;

}
try
{  
    /*return error: invalid columns in db.SaveChanges*/
    db.SaveChanges();
```

For my Model:

```
   public partial class tbl_transaction
   {
         public int transferevent { get; set; }
         public string transactionno { get; set; }
         public Nullable<int> itemno { get; set; }
         public string assetdesc { get; set; }
         public string serialno { get; set; }
         public string barcode { get; set; }
         public string sourcelocationid { get; set; }
         public string destinationid { get; set; }
         public Nullable<System.DateTime> transactiondate { get; set; }
         public Nullable<int> quantity { get; set; }
         public string unitmeasure { get; set; }
         public string remarks { get; set; }
         public string @ref { get; set; }
         public string actg_rem { get; set; }
         public string label { get; set; }
         public string station { get; set; }
         public string line_model { get; set; }
         public string process_assign { get; set; }
         public string status { get; set; }
         public string controlno { get; set; }
         public string category { get; set; }
         public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_maintain { get; set; }
         public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_repair { get; set; }
         public string defect { get; set; }
         public string repair_made { get; set; }
         public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_next_maintain { get; set; }
   }
```

Every time I execute the query, it always return invalid column name. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What's the excat exception message? I expect the invalid column name in the message of the exception or inner exception?

Comment: nobody can help you with info you have given, take time and post more info to help us to help you..

Comment: It's invalid column names in the inner exception.,

Comment: this is the error message: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: If you inspect the exception in the debugger you should be able to look at the InnerException property, as it suggests. This should give you more information